# SQL SP runs Slow

Tags: sql

Hi 
I am using an SP which takes 7 minutes in a server which has 7336 recrds
and 6seconds in another server which has 3500 records.

Can anybody help me to know why is it happening?

Thanks,
-Divya

THE SP:

SELECT WORKSHEET_ID
       FROM       PERSON PER
       INNER JOIN PERSON EMPLEE 
       ON EMPLEE.PERSON_ID = PER.PERSON_ID 
       AND
       dbo.FN_CHECKRPTSECURITY(EMPLEE.PERSON_ID, @p_SEC_ACCOUNT_ID) > 0

```
  LEFT JOIN SEARCH_ASSIGNMENT_VW PERSON_ASGN 
  ON PERSON_ASGN.ASSIGNMENT_ID =    
                  dbo.FN_GETRPTASSIGNMENTID(EMPLEE.PERSON_ID)

 LEFT JOIN LOOKUP EMPLEE_ASGN_STAT
 ON EMPLEE_ASGN_STAT.TYPE_ = 'ASSIGNMMENT_STATUS_CODE'
 AND EMPLEE_ASGN_STAT.CODE = PERSON_ASGN.ASGN_STAT_CODE
 INNER JOIN 
(SELECT w1.ASSIGNMENT_ID, w1.WORKSHEET_ID, w1.EFFECTIVE_DATE, w1.APPROVED_BY, w3.CREATED_BY
    FROM WORKSHEET_PAYROLL_VW w1 
    INNER JOIN WORKSHEET w3 
    ON w3.WORKSHEET_ID = w1.WORKSHEET_ID
    WHERE w1.EFFECTIVE_DATE = CASE 
                             WHEN @p_MOST_RECENT_ONLY = 'Y' 
                             THEN (SELECT MAX(w2.EFFECTIVE_DATE)
                                   FROM WORKSHEET_PAYROLL_VW w2
                                   WHERE w1.ASSIGNMENT_ID = w2.ASSIGNMENT_ID 
                                   AND (ISNULL(@p_WKS_EFFECTIVE_DATE,w2.EFFECTIVE_DATE) =w2.EFFECTIVE_DATE)) 
                             ELSE ISNULL(@p_WKS_EFFECTIVE_DATE,w1.EFFECTIVE_DATE)
                             END

       )
 PERSON_WKS
 ON PERSON_WKS.ASSIGNMENT_ID = dbo.FN_GETRPTASSIGNMENTID(EMPLEE.PERSON_ID)
 INNER JOIN  
  (SELECT ASSIGNMENT_ID, VALUE
   FROM ASSIGNMENT_HISTORY AH
   WHERE    FIELD_NAME ='HOME PAYROLL GROUP' 
   AND EFFECTIVE_DATE =  (SELECT MAX(EFFECTIVE_DATE)
                          FROM ASSIGNMENT_HISTORY 
                          WHERE ASSIGNMENT_ID = AH.ASSIGNMENT_ID 
                          AND   EFFECTIVE_DATE <=getDate() 
                          AND   FIELD_NAME = 'HOME PAYROLL GROUP')

    )HOME_PAYROLL 
    ON HOME_PAYROLL.ASSIGNMENT_ID = dbo.FN_GETRPTASSIGNMENTID(EMPLEE.PERSON_ID)

   WHERE 
    (@p_SELECTED_PERSON_ONLY = 'N' OR EMPLEE.PERSON_ID = @p_PERSON_ID)
     AND
    (@p_ASGN_STAT_CODE IS NULL OR PERSON_ASGN.ASGN_STAT_CODE = SUBSTRING(@p_ASGN_STAT_CODE,1,1)
     OR PERSON_ASGN.ASGN_STAT_CODE = SUBSTRING(@p_ASGN_STAT_CODE,2,1))
     AND
    (@p_POLICY_ID IS NULL OR PERSON_ASGN.PROGRAM_CODE = @p_POLICY_ID)
     AND
    (@p_HOME_COUNTRY_ID IS NULL OR PERSON_ASGN.HOMECOUNTRYID=@p_HOME_COUNTRY_ID) 
     AND
    (@p_HOME_CITY_ID IS NULL OR PERSON_ASGN.HOMECITYID=@p_HOME_CITY_ID )
     AND
    (@p_HOME_COMPANY_ID IS NULL OR PERSON_ASGN.HOMEBUSINESSID=@p_HOME_COMPANY_ID ) 
    AND
    (@p_HOME_DIVISION_ID IS NULL OR PERSON_ASGN.HOMECOMPONENTID=@p_HOME_DIVISION_ID )
     AND
    (@p_HOST_COUNTRY_ID IS NULL OR PERSON_ASGN.HOSTCOUNTRYID=@p_HOST_COUNTRY_ID )
     AND
    (@p_HOST_CITY_ID IS NULL OR PERSON_ASGN.HOSTCITYID=@p_HOST_CITY_ID )
     AND
    (@p_HOST_COMPANY_ID IS NULL OR PERSON_ASGN.HOSTBUSINESSID=@p_HOST_COMPANY_ID )
     AND
    (@p_HOST_DIVISION_ID IS NULL OR PERSON_ASGN.HOSTCOMPONENTID=@p_HOST_DIVISION_ID )
     AND
    (@p_CREATED_BY IS NULL OR PERSON_WKS.CREATED_BY=@p_CREATED_BY )
     AND
    (@p_APPROVED_BY IS NULL OR PERSON_WKS.APPROVED_BY=@p_APPROVED_BY )
     AND
    (@p_payroll_code IS NULL OR HOME_PAYROLL.VALUE=@p_payroll_code )
```

ORDER BY PER.LAST_NAME ASC,
PER.FIRST_NAME ASC, 
PERSON_WKS.EFFECTIVE_DATE DESC

---

The Function in the 5th line is the one which is running slow. rest of the part is running in 4secs

---

The FUNCTION:
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
        @v_ASGN_COUNT   INT,
        @v_RESULT   INT

```
SELECT @v_ASGN_COUNT = COUNT(ASSIGNMENT_ID) --to find out if this employee has any assignment
FROM ASSIGNMENT
WHERE EXPATRIATE_PERSON_ID = @p_PERSON_ID AND
      ASGN_STAT_CODE IN ('PD','A','I')

IF(@v_ASGN_COUNT > 0)   --yes assignment, check against SECURITY_ASSIGNMENT_VW
BEGIN
    SELECT @v_RESULT = COUNT(ASSIGNMENT_ID)
    FROM SECURITY_ASSIGNMENT_VW
    WHERE SEC_ACCOUNT_ID = @p_SEC_ACCOUNT_ID AND
          ASSIGNMENT_ID IN (SELECT ASSIGNMENT_ID
                FROM ASSIGNMENT
                WHERE EXPATRIATE_PERSON_ID = @p_PERSON_ID AND
                      ASGN_STAT_CODE IN ('PD','A','I'))
END
ELSE    --no assignment, so check against SECURITY_PERSON_VW
BEGIN
    SELECT @v_RESULT = COUNT(PERSON_ID)
    FROM SECURITY_PERSON_VW 
    WHERE SEC_ACCOUNT_ID = @p_SEC_ACCOUNT_ID AND
          PERSON_ID = @p_PERSON_ID
END

RETURN @v_RESULT
```

END

Comment: Not without details, no.

Comment: Please provide the code of the Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Do the schemas match exactly... in particular check for missing indexes.

Comment: YES THE SCHEMAS MATCH EXACTLY.

Comment: :) by mistak caps lock was ON :)

Answer (score 1):

Well to begin with you have  scalar functions which will run significantly slower as the number of records increase becasue they process row-by-agonizing-row. Not only that you've used the  functions in joins which is a horrible practice if you need performance. You have a bunch of OR conditions which tend to slowness. And while it is too hard to actually read the code you posted (please try to format and only use all caps for keywords), I would suspect that some of those conditions are not sargable.

To know what is actually happening check the Execution plan (SQL Server) or  Explain Plan (mySQL and others I think) or the equivalent feature in your database. Likely you wil find table scans which of course are going to get significantly slower as the number of records increases.

You may also have a problem with parameter sniffing. Please google to see how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

One improvement would be to make sure that `dbo.FN_GETRPTSSIGNMENTID` only gets executed once.

Currently, it gets executed three times.
You can replace two of those calls by joining to the field of the (one) remaing call.

Something like

```
SELECT  WORKSHEET_ID 
FROM    PERSON PER
        INNER JOIN PERSON EMPLEE ON EMPLEE.PERSON_ID = PER.PERSON_ID AND dbo.FN_CHECKRPTSECURITY(EMPLEE.PERSON_ID, @p_SEC_ACCOUNT_ID) > 0
        INNER JOIN (
          SELECT  w1.ASSIGNMENT_ID
                  , w1.WORKSHEET_ID
                  , w1.EFFECTIVE_DATE
                  , w1.APPROVED_BY
                  , w3.CREATED_BY
          FROM    WORKSHEET_PAYROLL_VW w1 
                  INNER JOIN WORKSHEET w3 ON w3.WORKSHEET_ID = w1.WORKSHEET_ID
          WHERE   w1.EFFECTIVE_DATE = 
                    CASE  WHEN @p_MOST_RECENT_ONLY = 'Y' 
                    THEN  (
                            SELECT  MAX(w2.EFFECTIVE_DATE)
                            FROM    WORKSHEET_PAYROLL_VW w2
                            WHERE   w1.ASSIGNMENT_ID = w2.ASSIGNMENT_ID AND (ISNULL(@p_WKS_EFFECTIVE_DATE,w2.EFFECTIVE_DATE) = w2.EFFECTIVE_DATE)
                          ) 
                    ELSE ISNULL(@p_WKS_EFFECTIVE_DATE,w1.EFFECTIVE_DATE)
                    END

        ) PERSON_WKS ON PERSON_WKS.ASSIGNMENT_ID = dbo.FN_GETRPTASSIGNMENTID(EMPLEE.PERSON_ID)
        INNER JOIN  (
          SELECT  ASSIGNMENT_ID
                  , VALUE 
          FROM    ASSIGNMENT_HISTORY AH
          WHERE   FIELD_NAME ='HOME PAYROLL GROUP' 
                  AND EFFECTIVE_DATE = (
                                          SELECT  MAX(EFFECTIVE_DATE) 
                                          FROM    ASSIGNMENT_HISTORY   
                                          WHERE   ASSIGNMENT_ID = AH.ASSIGNMENT_ID 
                                                  AND EFFECTIVE_DATE <=getDate() 
                                                  AND  FIELD_NAME = 'HOME PAYROLL GROUP'
                                      )                   
        LEFT JOIN SEARCH_ASSIGNMENT_VW PERSON_ASGN ON PERSON_ASGN.ASSIGNMENT_ID = PERSON_WKS.ASSIGNMENT_ID
        LEFT JOIN LOOKUP EMPLEE_ASGN_STAT ON EMPLEE_ASGN_STAT.TYPE_ = 'ASSIGNMMENT_STATUS_CODE' AND EMPLEE_ASGN_STAT.CODE = PERSON_ASGN.ASGN_STAT_CODE
       ) HOME_PAYROLL ON HOME_PAYROLL.ASSIGNMENT_ID = PERSON_WKS.ASSIGNMENT_ID
 WHERE  (@p_SELECTED_PERSON_ONLY = 'N' OR EMPLEE.PERSON_ID = @p_PERSON_ID) 
        AND (@p_ASGN_STAT_CODE IS NULL OR PERSON_ASGN.ASGN_STAT_CODE = SUBSTRING(@p_ASGN_STAT_CODE,1,1) OR PERSON_ASGN.ASGN_STAT_CODE = SUBSTRING(@p_ASGN_STAT_CODE,2,1)) 
        AND (@p_POLICY_ID IS NULL OR PERSON_ASGN.PROGRAM_CODE = @p_POLICY_ID) 
        AND (@p_HOME_COUNTRY_ID IS NULL OR PERSON_ASGN.HOMECOUNTRYID=@p_HOME_COUNTRY_ID) 
        AND (@p_HOME_CITY_ID IS NULL OR PERSON_ASGN.HOMECITYID=@p_HOME_CITY_ID ) 
        AND (@p_HOME_COMPANY_ID IS NULL OR PERSON_ASGN.HOMEBUSINESSID=@p_HOME_COMPANY_ID ) 
        AND (@p_HOME_DIVISION_ID IS NULL OR PERSON_ASGN.HOMECOMPONENTID=@p_HOME_DIVISION_ID ) 
        AND (@p_HOST_COUNTRY_ID IS NULL OR PERSON_ASGN.HOSTCOUNTRYID=@p_HOST_COUNTRY_ID ) 
        AND (@p_HOST_CITY_ID IS NULL OR PERSON_ASGN.HOSTCITYID=@p_HOST_CITY_ID ) 
        AND (@p_HOST_COMPANY_ID IS NULL OR PERSON_ASGN.HOSTBUSINESSID=@p_HOST_COMPANY_ID ) 
        AND (@p_HOST_DIVISION_ID IS NULL OR PERSON_ASGN.HOSTCOMPONENTID=@p_HOST_DIVISION_ID ) 
        AND (@p_CREATED_BY IS NULL OR PERSON_WKS.CREATED_BY=@p_CREATED_BY ) 
        AND (@p_APPROVED_BY IS NULL OR PERSON_WKS.APPROVED_BY=@p_APPROVED_BY ) 
        AND (@p_payroll_code IS NULL OR HOME_PAYROLL.VALUE=@p_payroll_code )
ORDER BY 
        PER.LAST_NAME ASC
        , PER.FIRST_NAME ASC
        , PERSON_WKS.EFFECTIVE_DATE DESC
```